# Suppressing blazor input events fired

Tags: c#, blazor, event-propagation

Is there a way to completely stop all events on an EditForm component?

So for instance, I have a button, that fires an onclick event, but I don't want the whole form to run. I just want the button event to fire, nothing else.

At the moment, when I type in the text box, even if I do not click a button. And click anywhere on my page. The form re-runs, executing my code inside.

I have tried using `@onclick:stopPropagation="true"` on my button, and also creating a div and putting the onclick in there, but it stills runs my code.

I have reset my code back to how it was before

```
 @if (item.Option1 != null)
    {
        <li>
            <label for="txtEmail" col="col-sm-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;&nbsp; Current Answer = @item.Option1 </label>
            <div class="form-group row">

                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <InputText id="option1" Placeholder="Edit Option 1" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@CreateQuizModel.Option1"></InputText>
                        @if (item.Option1.Contains("Empty"))
                        {
                            <button type="submit" @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option1, CreateQuizModel.Option1, item.Id))" class="btn btn-success">Add New Answer</button>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <button @onclick="@(e => DeleteAnswer(item.QuizTitle, null, item.Option2, item.Option3, item.Option4, item.Option5, item.Position))" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Answer</button>
                        }

                        &nbsp; <button @onclick="@(e => EditAnswer(item.Option1, CreateQuizModel.Option1, item.Id))" class="btn btn-info">Edit Answer</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
    }
```

So for example if I click the last button, I only want the onclick event to fire.

Is the issue, because it is in an if block? If so I didn't think that would matter, as the page has rendered, showing me the button. The issue is that when I type into the input field, it's always firing the code, after I click out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `type="button"` on your button - it should suppress the form submission and validation.

The re-rendering is another story - when an `EventCallback` such as `onclick` fires, blazor re-renders the component that fired the event, its parent, and its siblings. In your case that's the form. While you can override the `ShouldRender` lifecycle method, it can be a tad cumbersome to do. So, to an extent, the questions is "what is the problem with the form re-rendering since it is supposed to".